# Able to decrypt the message using different key

Tags: encryption, cryptography, java-security, tripledes

I create following singleton class to encrypt and decrypt the string messages.

```
public class EncryptionHelper {
  private Cipher ecipher;
  private Cipher dcipher;
  private SecretKey key;
  private byte iv[] = { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

  private static EncryptionHelper instance;

  public static EncryptionHelper getInstance( String defKey ) {
    synchronized( EncryptionHelper.class ) {
      if ( null == instance ) {
        try {
          instance = new EncryptionHelper( defKey );
        } catch( Exception e ) {
                  }
      }
    }
    return instance;
  }

  private EncryptionHelper( String defKey )
    throws Exception {
    DESedeKeySpec keyspec = new DESedeKeySpec( defKey.getBytes() );
    SecretKeyFactory keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance( "TripleDES" );
    key = keyfactory.generateSecret( keyspec );
    ecipher = Cipher.getInstance( "TripleDES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" );
    dcipher = Cipher.getInstance( "TripleDES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" );
    ecipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec( iv ) );
    dcipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec( iv ) );
  }

  public String encrypt( String str ) {
    try {
      byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes( "UTF-8" );
      byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal( utf8 );
      String val = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( enc );
      return val;
    } catch( UnsupportedEncodingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e ) {
    }
    return str;
  }

  public String decrypt( String str ) {
    try {
      byte[] dec = Base64.getDecoder().decode( str );
      byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal( dec );
      return new String( utf8, "UTF8" );
    } catch( IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | IOException e ) {
    }
    return str;
  }  
}
```

When I tried to use encrypt and decrypt method of this class using two different program with different key as follows.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  EncryptionHelper encryptionHelper = EncryptionHelper.getInstance( "000000000000ffffffffffff" );
  System.out.println( encryptionHelper.encrypt( "ABCDEFGH" ) );
}
```

Output is ::: **n+0SEJQDXwfvpdMIdetNow==**

and

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  // Use different key to decrypt
  EncryptionHelper encryptionHelper = EncryptionHelper.getInstance( "111111111111ffffffffffff" );
  // Use output of previous call as input to decrypt
  System.out.println( encryptionHelper.decrypt( "n+0SEJQDXwfvpdMIdetNow==" ) );
}
```

Output is ::: **ABCDEFGH**

As you can see I am using different keys while using encrypt and decrypt method but still the program is able to decrypt the exact value using wrong key.

Can you guys help me to know, why it is behaving like this, why I am able to decrypt using wrong key?

Comment: please be aware that String.getBytes() does not convert from hex...

Answer (score 0):

> why I am able to decrypt using wrong key?

... because you are not using the second key, but the key that was used with the first call to `getInstance`

if you don't see that, answer the following question to yourself ... on your SECOND call to `getInstance`, when `instance` has already a value and is not `NULL`, how does `defKey` influence the instance? (hint: it doesn't)

Comment: I believe you have not checked it properly, both client programs are two different independent programs and with their own main() method.

Comment: in that case please add a string containing the defKey parameter to your helper, and throw an exception if you call get instance with another string...

Comment: Not possible to use this workaround, because that way key will become constant in code, and known to developer.  I want multiple clients to use their own key to encrypt/decrypt messages. Issue is simple to understand, why it is possible to decrypt using different key. Is anything wrong with algorithm or code?

Comment: I did not mean to hardcode the key... my guess is that you call once with the other key ... if you store and compare the parameter you can detect that